# LINQ Select From DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

Just started to play around with datatable and LINQ today.
I have a datatable that gets a list of Names From SQL database.
I am looking to return a specific name from the dt using LINQ.

I have tried the following code with no success at this. Is there something that i am doing wrong with the code.

dt returns a full list of names i am just looking to reduce the names down to one name. There is a name in the adventureworks database called Blade i am trying to display this only.

```
 DataTable dt =  DAL.GetNames();
      try
      {
          var q = from myrow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  where myrow.Field<string>("Name") =="Blade"
                  select myrow;
          dataGridView1.DataSource = q;
      }
```

I have tried to replace the == with a .equals.
I am totally new to the concept of using a Language intergrated query.

when i run the code noting happens i dont get any errors ect just no data returned.

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Also, why are you using this instead of actual LINQ2SQL?

Comment: @Stu: How else do you use Linq with a DataTable?

Comment: Im just playing around with LINQ. Updated the Question

Comment: What happens if you just do foreach (from myrow in dt.AsEnumerable() select myrow) { Console.WriteLine(myrow.Field<string>("Name"); }

Comment: @IAbstract: when you have linq2sql, why are you using a DataTable at all?

Comment: Noting guys at all when i return the datatable to the datagridview i can see Name Blade along with all the other names in the table. when i try any of the above i just dont get anything at all returning even when i debug i can see noting.

Comment: am i dispalying a var correctly in a datagridview?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're defining your query but not actually running it.

Your line:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = q;
```

Needs to be:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = q.AsDataView();
```